Tensorflow Serving: Adding warm start data at runtime
I'm trying to dynamically add warm-start data for our models via the SavedModel Warmup method (https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/saved_model_warmup). In our case, we need to actually have the model running in order to do some request input filtering. Is it possible to use the reload config request to reload the model and have it run with warm start? Currently I'm finding that after the reload request, it does not do a full reload, it just refreshes:
2024-06-07 20:32:47.215567: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:465] Adding/updating models.
2024-06-07 20:32:47.215629: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:594]  (Re-)adding model: response_prediction_3028.griffin.148
2024-06-07 20:32:47.215705: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:486] Finished adding/updating models
2024-06-07 20:33:07.290652: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/model_service_impl.cc:47] 
Config entry
    index : 0
...

Is there any way to force it to do a full reload rather than a re-add? If I restart the docker container it is able to pick up on the warm-start data file.
